# Await fetch holding component from rendering until fetch is done

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, next.js

Here I am fetching data for SSR and dispatch that data from Client.

```
const MyPage = ({
  myFetch1,
  myFetch2,
  myFetch3,
}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  dispatch(doSomething1(myFetch1));
  dispatch(doSomething2(myFetch2));
  dispatch(doSomething3(myFetch3));

  return (
    <Page>
      <Head />

      <MyOtherItem />
    </Page>
  );
};

MyPage.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const myFetch1 = await myFetch1();
  const myFetch2 = await myFetch2();
  const myFetch3 = await myFetch3();

  return {
    myFetch1,
    myFetch2,
    myFetch3,
  };
};
```

When i click on the link to route on this page

Issue:

1. The whole UI get freeze until fetching has done.
2. What is the best way to fetch that data
3. What is the best way to dispatch that data.

Comment: I think,  this is the intended behavior with getInitialProps(). the component will wait for initial props

Comment: Yes it is. How can i avoid that? Do i need to fetch that on client side?

Comment: yes, a simple way to fetch it on the client-side. it won't freeze your UI

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of Server-side rendering is to fetch all data before populate it through page props for Front-end manipulation.

Although I found this concept pretty useful, since it prevents component re-rendering.

In case you really need to send your request on client side I would suggest you to use SWR hook which was developed by Next.js team:
For more info and code snippets, head to the following link:
https://github.com/vercel/swr